# Video 'autoplay' only sometimes successful

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to have a video slideshow that auto repeats as well as starts automatically. Unfortunately it seems that the video only sometimes autoplays: from my experiments it is likely that the video autoplays when reloading the page if it is already loaded, as well as if the page is navigated to from another part of the site. As this video is meant to be running on my home page this isn't really an option. This may be a browser related issue as I don't think there are any bugs that could cause this, I am using the latest version of chrome.

```js
var videos = ["6", "5", "3", "8", "7", "2"];

function nextVideo() {
    var current = videoSource.getAttribute("src");
    current = current.slice(9, -4);
    var position = videos.indexOf(current);
    var newPos;
    if (position == videos.length - 1) {
        newPos = videos[0];
    } else {
        newPos = videos[position + 1];
    }

    videoSource.setAttribute("src", "videos/No" + newPos + ".mp4");
    videoId.currentTime = 0;
    videoId.load();
    videoId.play();
}
```

```html
<video autoplay id="videoId" onended="nextVideo()">
    <source src="videos/No6.mp4" id="videoSrc">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="your_video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can see **mozilla developer** video [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) for better reference.

Comment: How is that helpful? Please explain.

Comment: Somehow this sorts out the issue, but then that obviously causes issues where I can't have audio, where I need audio - how can I have both audio and autoplay?

Answer (score 0):

Sound should be `muted` for some browsers who only autoplay when muted:

```
<video autoplay muted id="videoId" onended="nextVideo()">
    <source src="https://app.coverr.co/s3/mp4/Mock-up.mp4" id="videoSrc">
</video>
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/WPrMrG